# How do you consume http response content asynchronously with Apache's HTTP async client?

Tags: java, apache-httpasyncclient

I'm new to Java NIO. I'm using it to make HTTP Get requests. The requests executes properly, but I am unable to figure out how to get the content of the response.

For example,

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
httpClient.start();
url = buildUrl(); //builds the url for the GET request
BasicAsyncResponseConsumer consumer = new BasicAsyncResponseConsumer();
 Future<HttpResponse> future = httpClient.execute(HttpAsyncMethods.createGet(url), consumer, null)
```

Now how do I get the content of the response? On printing future, I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: application/json, Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 20:21:47 GMT, Content-Length: 903, Connection: keep-alive] [Content-Length: 903,Chunked: false]
```

My response (on the browser) is 903 characters, so I know the it makes the request correctly. However, how do I print out the json content of the result?

Comment: Which library are you using? you don't appear to be using NIO.

Comment: I've been using NIO?

Comment: You might have used NIO before, but not in the code you mention here. hint: are you using any classes in the `java.nio` package?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways for you to approach this.

One, call `get()` on the `Future` returned by `execute`, blocking until a result is ready. Once the result is ready, `get()` will return the [`HttpResponse`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) object which you can use to retrieve the content with [`getEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity()). The [`HttpEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) has an [`InputStream`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()). Read it however you think is appropriate.

Two, provide a smarter `HttpAsyncResponseConsumer` implementation than `BasicAsyncResponseConsumer` which reads (and closes) the `HttpResponse`'s `HttpEntity` and produces a value that can be consumed by the `FutureCallback` value that is expected as the third argument to `HttpAsyncClient#execute`. This solution will not block your current thread.

Comment: get() will be called only when all the response content has been stored in a local buffer if we use BasicAsyncResponseConsumer . But thats not what the ask is. We want to stream the response body directly and not store it in local buffer.